# Write-Host cannot parse variable's property

Tags: variables, powershell, properties, write-host

It's quite weird that `Write-Host` doesn't seem to parse variable's property.

```
PS C:\Users\x> $v=@{item1="kkk";item2="aaa"}
PS C:\Users\x> $v.Keys|%{$v.Item($_)}
kkk
aaa
PS C:\Users\x> Write-Host "$v.Count elements"
System.Collections.Hashtable.Count elements
PS C:\Users\x> $v.Count
2
PS C:\Users\x> $v
Name                           Value
----                           -----
item1                          kkk
item2                          aaa
```

You could see, `$v` is a hashtable and

```
$v.Count
```

prints 2. But why does

```
Write-Host "$v.Count"
```

print out `System.Collections.Hashtable.Count`? This is not what I expected.

Comment: I don't have a solid answer for why it does it, but it's a behavior that I've noticed a lot - you can include a simple variable in a string, but not members with dot notation. If you want to have that work, you have to put it in a single variable first (```$count = $v.count```), use string formatting (```Write-Host ("{0} elements" -f $v.Count)```) or provide it as separate elements (```Write-Host $v.Count "elements"```)

Answer (score 7):

Text representation of `$v` is `System.Collections.Hashtable` (`[string]$v` or `"$v"`). And `"$v.Count elements"` means `{text representation of $v}.Count elements` not `{text representation of $v.Count} elements`, so for me it is expected that you get `System.Collections.Hashtable.Count elements` as result.

`Write-Host` is not responsible for expanding double quoted strings. It done by PowerShell before it invoke `Write-Host`.

> ```
> "$v.Count"
> ```
>
> prints 2

For me it prints `System.Collections.Hashtable.Count`. `2` printed by `$v.Count` not by `"$v.Count"`.

You should use `"$($v.Count) elements"` to get expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! This extra $ solves my problem(interpretation)!